# Disable isolated scope for angularjs components

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

Is there a way to disable isolated scope for angularjs components? By default they are isolated and you'd need to go $scope.$parent

Angular docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component "Comparison between Directive definition and Component definition") says that scope is "No (scope is always isolate)", but surely there is a way to turn it off.

Comment: Why would you like to do it ?

Comment: If you not need isolate scope you can use simple directive

Comment: As said; a directive can be used instead. There's a good reason why components were forced to use isolated scope. In order for a thing to be componentized, it should be isolated from its parent. No isolation == no componentization.